# can't uninstall gnat-gpl-2014

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I recently installed GNAT-GPL-2014 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but I made a mistake and I installed it in the wrong directory. Therefore, I want to uninstall it and install it correctly but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the file from http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations and after decompressing it I ran ./doinstall @KarlRichter

Comment: Hard to say where `./doinstall` wrote the files. Is there a `README`, `INSTALL` or a script which is named ~uninstall or ~remove? I didn't manage to download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I solved it by running

```
sudo apt-get install gnat
```

and then I installed all the packages recommended. Now eclipse does recognise GNAT.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the doinstall.sh file:

> To install GNAT, you need to specify a base directory.
>       All the files will be installed in subdirectories
>       that are created under this directory.

It sounds like you can just delete the entire base directory you specified in the install and re-install to a new directory.  There is no uninstall method in the doinstall.sh file.

Comment: I changed the default directory, and now eclipse doesn't find it.
So can I specify the new directory in eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with eclipse, but I imagine there is a way to change the directory where it looks for the files.